# Testing without changing application code

Tags: java, scala, testing, mocking

First off, I am using Scala, but any Java approach will work. (I will use Java code as examples for easier comprehension.)

Say I have a `Connection` interface and its implementations `RealConnection` and `FakeConnection`.

I want to have **two** entries into my application: A release entry and a test entry. I want to code my application as I would normally and just start my test that uses all the classes the release version does, but with the one exception that it uses `FakeConnection` instead of `RealConnection`.

My application accesses the Connection via `Connection.get()`.

What I don't want is something like this:

```
public static Connection get() {
    if ( isReleaseVersion )
        return new RealConnection();
    return new FakeConnection();
}
```

I want my application code to not be polluted by this kind of code.

What's possible would be to have a `Config` object, as in:

```
public static Connection get() {
    return Config.getConnectionFactory().get();
}
```

The problem here is that I need to change my `Config` class every time I want to test. I will probably use this method if no other is present.

What I don't want to use, are setters. I want to deal with `final` variables, or functions! Not something like:

```
public class TestEntry {
    public static void main(String... args) }
        Config.connectionFactory = new FakeConnectionFactory();
        Config.databaseConnection = new FakeDatabaseConnection(); // Singleton, no factory needed.
        MyApplication.start(args); // the ReleaseEntry is somewhere else!
    }
}
```

What I don't want to use, either, is `Guice`. I would have to redefine my modules everytime I want to do a test. Also, I'd not rather not use it in Scala in general.

`Reflection` would be a possibility, but errors would only appear in runtime, so it's not a very .

Are there any alternatives to accomplish what I want?

Do I have to go with the `Config` way?

Regards.

Comment: Sounds like Dependency Injection is what you are looking for...

Comment: I know about Dependency Injection, it's not what I'm looking for, though.

Comment: DI is what you want, you just don't know it yet.  If it's just about testing, then mocks are your answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate why Dependency Injection is not what you are looking for? Imho the cake pattern exactly addresses all your requirements, because you can statically mix in your Connection type. Maybe [this](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) might help you.

Comment: As I said, I want to have little to no pollution in my application code. Implicits was the way to go. Thanks everyone, nothing else to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains a contradiction:

You want to make something globally available

> My application accesses the `Connection` via `Connection.get()`

that is not stored using a variable

> What I don't want to use, are setters. I want to deal with final variables, or functions!

Yet you want to provide this implementation at runtime.

Others mentioned 'dependency injection' which is a form of 'inversion of control', the requirements in your question tell me that that is what you want.

If you don't want to use variables, you will have to pass the correct instance to the components using the connection. With Scala you have the option to pass it `implicitly` instead of `explicitly`.

```
class MyComponent(name:String)(implicit c:Configuration)

implicit val configuration = new TestConfiguration

//note that the configuration is passed in implicitly
val m = new MyComponent("foo")
```

This requirement makes other options tricky as well:

> Reflection would be a possibility, but errors would only appear in runtime

If you don't want to change any of your requirements you might (in theory) be able to do it with something like Scala macro's. If that is what you want I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: This answer is very close to what I'm looking for. I'm not sure why I'm downvoted but whatever. I think implicits is what I was missing in my thought process. Thank you very much!